# GWT GIN HOW TO: injection of remote services

Tags: gwt, dependency-injection, gwt-gin

The [gin tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/google-gin/wiki/GinTutorial#whb) seems to imply that to inject remote services all you need to do is annotate with `@Inject`.

Do you you still need to define this in a module somewhere or is the point that you can just annotate with `@Inject` and it will work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gin has automatic support for remote services, as outlined in the tutorial you mentioned:

> Every time Gin is asked to inject an asynchronous remote service, it will inject an instance retrieved through calling GWT.create on its regular remote service.

Therefore, it will 'just work'.